# eEach virtual host with different php cinfiguration

Tags: php, webserver, apache2-module

I have two virtualhosts on an apache web server. There is a document root for each of them:

```
>>/var/www/vhosts/
```

I set up a php-fpm, now I want to set different open_basedir for each of them. 
I removed

```
>>/etc/php.ini
```

then created two php.ini in different folders.
Then to the ini vhost config file I added the code:

```
PHPINIDir /var/www/vhosts/website1
```

but when I get `phpinfo()` nothing is different than before. I think I missed something!
How can I force php-fpm to get both php.ini for each virtualhost ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need a php.ini.

You must add :

php_admin_value open_basedir /OPEN_BASEDIR_FOLDER_HERE

To each VHOST config file.

Comment: in which config file ? /etc/php-fpm.d/mydomaon.conf or /etc/hhtpd/site-avalable/mydomain.conf   ?

Comment: i did the exact soloution in apache webserver . no error on restarting php-fpm and httpd ! but root shellers still can browse all over the machin and in phpifo , open_basedir shown "not valued" . what am i missing ?